# How can I transplant wild ground cherries into garden beds?

Tags: vegetables, seeds, transplanting, fruits

I recently found ground cherries growing wild on my property and I want to put them in beds and harvest seeds from them.

How and when should I transplant them?

Answer (score 2):

These plants won't like their roots disturbed. Starting from seed next year might be easier. If you want to transplant mature plants, here are a few tips that might make the survival rate higher:

- Look for an overcast week, where there will be rain, and little to no direct sun for a period of time. If the sunny weather is relentless, you can build a small shading frame with slats or cheesecloth, to cut back on direct lighting while they recover.
- Take as large a rootball as possible for each crown. The fewer cut roots the better. Try not to crack/break the rootball.
- Plant in loose, well drained organic topsoil. Hard soil like dry clay can cause moisture pockets when planting, or retard root growth.
- Water heavily after planting. Get the soil good and wet. Water again when the top layer is dry.
- Mulch with 2-3" of organic matter (such as shredded bark, mushroom soil, or chopped leaves).
- Once you see new growth, you can fertilize.